# Disable gcloud notification

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, gcloud

Is there any way to disable this notification:

```
* - There is an upgrade available for your cluster(s).

To upgrade nodes to the latest available version, run
  $ gcloud container clusters upgrade NAME
```

when I run gcloud container clusters list?

Comment: Upgrade the cluster?

Comment: yeah... that would be a solution, but i dont want to update the clusters right now as development teams are actively working on them... I find it strange that there is no option to suppress these notifications

Comment: If you suppressed the notification, you might forget that you're running outdated and possibly insecure code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently this isn't supported, and since this could be a feature that could be implemented I created a [case](https://issuetracker.google.com/123401612) for the GCP GKE team.

As mentioned before, this helps you to be up to date with the [latest versions](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/release-notes) and avoid known issues or have the latest security patches for example.

My recommendation will be always be using the latest stable version (which usually will be the default when creating a cluster)